# Java: Multiple JScrollPanes show view on 1 common component

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

how (if at all) can I make multiple JScrollPanes have different views on 1 common component (a JTable in this case). Every time I set the viewport of a scrollpane, the previous scrollpane's view disappears...

Cheers,
Max

Answer (score 1):

A `Component` can have only 1 parent.  You can't put the same `JTable` in two `JScrollPanes`.  You can, however, create two `JTable`s backed by the same model, and put those two tables into their own scroll panes.

Comment: Yes, that's my current solution, but it causes some problems which I try to eliminate by using the same table. I wasn't aware of that the JTable is actually added when used in a JScrollPane, but it seems to be added on a JViewPort...